# Navigation from modal not working in .net maui

Tags: maui

How do you navigate from a modal popup?

I've opened a modal page using await NavigationService.PushModalAsync() which I'm using as a login page. With a successful login, I'm trying to close the modal and navigate to an account page.

await NavigationService.PopModalAsync();

await NavigationService.PushAsync();

The modal closes, but it will not show the page specified in the PushAsync Method.
Both lines of code run, no errors thrown.
The page the pushasync() goes to, displays fine if the login modal window is skipped.

The above code is in a [RelayCommand] method using community toolkit mvvm

What do I need to do to get the above to work?

Comment: Unclear what it could be. Maybe make a public github repo with just enough code to make the problem happen.

Comment: Could you provide some code related？

Comment: The code is above. just open(pushmodalasync) a modal page, then try close (popmodalasync) the modal and navigate (pushasync) to another page. The navigate never happens, but no errors. I unfortunately dont have the time currently to create a working sample project on github to show those 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Unfortunately your needs cannot be achieved. As mentioned in the figure above, the login page you created is a modal page, therefore it can navigate only to another modal page. When you call `PopModalAsync`, the login page pops up from `ModalStack` directly, meanwhile the (moldeless) page at the top of the `NavigationStack` will appear. And you call `PushAsync` to navigate to the account page in modal page, it doesn't work.